# log4net separate configuration file

Tags: c#, configuration, log4net

I'm using `log4net` in my project.
so far I used the `App.config` file as a configuration file,
but now I want to put it in a different file.

here's what I did :

I moved `<log4net> ... </log4net>` to the new file

(`<log4net>` is right after `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`)

on the `App.config` I changed the code as follow :

```
<configSections>
   <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>

<log4net configSource="log4net.config"/>
```

and changed this line (that I suspect that this is the line with the problem) :

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

this line is not written to the `Assemblyinfo.cs` though. don't know if I should...

it is worth mentioning that this is working as long as the `log4net.config` file is inside the `bin\debug` folder, so that is why I suspect the line with the assembly making the problem, I want the file to be easily visible on the solution, alongside the `App.config` file and not in the `bin` folder. Also, it's work if I put there a string with the full path of the `log4net.config`, but this will make problem to use it on another computer, how can I make it work? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the property "Copy to output directory" for the log4net.config file is set to "Copy if newer". This way it is always copied to the bin/debug or bin/release folder when you run your project.